# Rails error resolving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to overwrite the existing users table in the database. I have manually deleted the migration file `user.rb` and model file. After that when I type  `rails g model User email:string password:string`
it creates the above files again but when I run the `rake db:migrate` command it just gives me the following error:

```
rake db:migrate                                                                                                                                          
== 20150413203600 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================                                                                                                               
-- create_table(:users)                                                                                                                                                                       
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                 
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:                                                                                                                 

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255), "password" varchar(255), "created_at" dateti
me, "updated_at" datetime) /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your `db/schema.rb` file, you will see that you already have a users table. Deleting the migration file doesn't do anything besides not running the migration file if you were to run `rake db:migrate` on another computer. Run `rake db:rollback` will delete the last thing that you rake db:migrate, then generate your new user migration along with `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have deleted the migration file, as rails would have used the migration file under a `rake db:rollback` command to delete the users table for you.

If you don't mind losing ALL your tables, and since you're using SQLite3, you can look in your `db` folder for a file called `development.sqlite3` and possibly `test.sqlite3`.  Delete those and you no longer have any database tables at all and you can run migrations to re-create them.

If you ONLY want to drop the `users` table, delete the migrations that you've recently generated to "create user table" and then create a migration `rails g migration DropUsersTable` then modify it to look like the following

```
class DropUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Run migration and that will drop your existing users table. Then, you should delete the migration file.  As I said, it's not good practice to delete migration files but in this case since you've destroyed the migration that created the original user table, you should destroy the migration that dropped that table.

At this point, you have no migrations that reference `users` table and you have no `users` table so you can now generate the migration to create it and this time it should work.

If you change your mind and you want to drop the users table again, remember, DO NOT delete the migration file, just do `rake db:rollback` then adjust the migration file to create the table as you'd like it and then run `rake db:migrate` again.